# A new session could not be created. error in code for appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress) this error is show if I run my code second time . Works fine for the first time

Writing a code for selenium

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException{

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "AndroidTest");
        System.out.println("iii");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/gurpreet/Desktop/nimbuzz-3.2.0-rc4-debug.apk");
        System.out.println("iii");
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        driver.findElement(By.id("com.nimbuzz:id/btnSignInSplash")).click();
}
}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to this /

Comment: Close the first one that you run which is still running before trying to run it again.

Comment: @dcc Do I have to close Appium every time to run ?

Comment: you have to close the session through code.

Answer (score 11):

try with the following

In appium tool ->general settings- > select overriding existing sessions

Answer (score 3):

a) add a code that quits your driver.

driver.Quit();

b) over ride the session through the Appium.

c) If you still get the error then you have to Kill the process of ChromeDriver  from the task manager. and try running your script again.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your code  :

```
public void teardown(){
driver.quit();   }
```

The problem is that the test run did not close and you were trying to run it again, adding the above code ensures that the previous run is over.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code

`public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "C:/Users/gurpreet/Desktop/nimbuzz-3.2.0-rc4-debug.apk");
   WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}`

This code assumes that your appium server is running on localhost and port 4723